# Yii2 / Kartik Select 2 Tags - form field submitting data in extra array brackets

Tags: php, yii2, jquery-select2

Hopefully this makes sense to someone.

I'm using Kartik-V Select2 widgets in a ActiveForm, with 'multiple' and 'tags' enabled. I'm using this elsewhere in my application and it is working fine there, and on submission the array data is sent as I would expect in the appropriate form field. From there I can easily implode the array and save to database in the controller action.

However in a different section of my app, with exactly the same configuration in the view, model and controller, the array is being posted as an additional form field (as can be seen watching the post event in the firefox console).

What I'm seeing in the firefox console is:

```
-----------------------------366976194315951562394252057249

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Notes[notes_to]"


-----------------------------366976194315951562394252057249

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Notes[notes_to][]"

admin

-----------------------------366976194315951562394252057249

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="Notes[notes_to][]"

kennettm
```

So where I would expect to receive the array in `Notes[notes_to]`, it is actually coming through in `Notes[notes_to][]` but I can't for the life of me figure out how to access and handle these values in my controller, or how to get the array of tags submitted in Notes[notes_to] where I want it.

Thanks in advance.

***** EDIT *******

Thanks @Muhammed. I am expecting to received an array `['admin','kennettm']` (as with other areas of my app where I've used this setup), however in this instance that is not what is happening.

I've got the model and CRUD generated by Gii for the Notes section, so it does have its own MVC setup however the notes _form file in this case is rendered on the site index, so in this case the model is being loaded in the Site controller and is handled there. I can confirm that the same issue is occurring regardless of where I render the _form file, be it in the index or in the Notes section view.

I would expect that the data be returned in `$notesmodel->notes_to` as an array as mentioned above, which is then easily imploded and saved to db. However the data is not there on form submission, and "Public" is being saved every time. For the sake of testing, I removed the if statement, set the controller to implode the array and ensure that I add tags (so the array is sure to be there), however then I am receiving an error exception `"implode(): Argument must be an array"`.

Snippet of my intended controller code is below. The controller checks to see if any tags have been added to the field. If tags are present, there should be an array which can be imploded and saved. Otherwise if no tags are present, it will revert back to a simple string "Public' and save that instead.

```
$notesmodel = new Notes();

if ($notesmodel->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
    $notesmodel->notes_user = Yii::$app->user->identity->username;
    $notesmodel->notes_created = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
    if (!empty($notesmodel->notes_to)) {
        $notesmodel->notes_to = implode($notesmodel->notes_to);
    } else {
        $notesmodel->notes_to = 'Public';
    }
```

Comment: its the `Notes` model attributes array that is submitted as you are using the active form, are you not loading the post array into model in your controller ? show you controller action code where the form is submitted, if you are loading the model then the `$model->notes_to` will hold an array like `['admin','kennettm']`

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadOmerAslam, really appreciate your help! Post edited with some controller details

Comment: you are using `implode($notesmodel->notes_to);` but not specifying the glue to concat the array ? it should be `implode(",",$notesmodel->notes_to);` as what looks like you want to convert the array to the comma separated value if it is not empty  and then save?

Comment: by the way you can use the filter validator for this purpose too

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam ohhhh *forehead slap*. Thanks for pointing that out. I guess I would have figured that one out as soon as the code made it that far, but with the `if` finding an empty array in `$notesmodel->notes_to`, that silly mistake hadn't been of any issue yet. The `if` is going straight to the `else`. I'm so lost trying to get my head around what's happening with the form data!

Will have a look into the filter validator, thanks.

Comment: @MuhammadOmerAslam thanks for pointing me to the filter validator. Hahaha oh I do some funny things sometimes. I had taken the two tags fields in that form out of the string fields (because they were throwing validation errors being populated with arrays), and never put them into the "safe" list. That probably explains it lol. Cheers for the help.